# R - dplyr bootstrap issue

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics-bootstrap, broom

I have an issue understanding how to use the `dplyr` `bootstrap` function properly.

What I want is to generate a bootstrap distribution from two **randomly** assigned groups and compute the difference in means, like this for example :

```
library(dplyr) 
library(broom) 
data(mtcars) 

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(treat = sample(c(0, 1), 32, replace = T)) %>% 
  group_by(treat) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(disp)) %>% 
  summarise(m = m[treat == 1] - m[treat == 0])
```

The issue is that I need to repeat this operation `100`, `1000`, or more times.

Using `replicate`, I can do

```
frep = function(mtcars) mtcars %>% 
  mutate(treat = sample(c(0, 1), 32, replace = T)) %>% 
  group_by(treat) %>%
  summarise(m = mean(disp)) %>% 
  summarise(m = m[treat == 1] - m[treat == 0])

replicate(1000, frep(mtcars = mtcars), simplify = T) %>% unlist()
```

and get the distribution

[image]

I don't really get how to use `bootstrap`here. How should I start ?

```
mtcars %>% 
  bootstrap(10) %>% 
  mutate(treat = sample(c(0, 1), 32, replace = T)) 

mtcars %>% 
  bootstrap(10) %>% 
  do(tidy(treat = sample(c(0, 1), 32, replace = T)))
```

It's not really working. Where should I put the `bootstrap` pip ?

Thanks.

Comment: yes ! thank you. This is perfect. So can you explain me, I have to create a `data.frame` inside the `do` ? can you post your answer ? thanks again!

Comment: As we are creating a column 'treat', we wrap it with `data.frame` to get the output as data.frame.  The `.` signifies the contents of the dataset on the `lhs` of `%>%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `do` step, we wrap with `data.frame` and create the 'treat' column, then we can group by 'replicate' and 'treat' to get the `summarise`d output column

```
mtcars %>% 
    bootstrap(10) %>% 
    do(data.frame(., treat = sample(c(0,1), 32, replace=TRUE))) %>% 
    group_by(replicate, treat) %>% 
    summarise(m = mean(disp)) %>%
    summarise(m = m[treat == 1] - m[treat == 0])
    #or as 1 occurs second and 0 second, we can also use
    #summarise(m = last(m) - first(m))
```