# Stratified permutation with bootstrap

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I am experiencing issues in trying to stratify permutations.

My data look like this :

```
     gender party        value
1      F    Democrat      762
2      M    Democrat      484
3      F    Independent   327
4      M    Independent   239
5      F    Republican    468
6      M    Republican    477
```

What I am simply trying to do is to stratified random permutation by `party`

```
library(dplyr)
md %>% 
  group_by(party) %>% 
  mutate(perm = sample(gender))
```

Which gives me a correct random permutation

```
     gender party        value   perm
1      F    Democrat      762      M
2      M    Democrat      484      F
3      F    Independent   327      M
4      M    Independent   239      F
5      F    Republican    468      F
6      M    Republican    477      M
```

What I would like is to repeat this operation many times. Following the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548923/r-dplyr-bootstrap-issue) (non-stratification permutation)

```
library(broom) 
md %>% 
 bootstrap(100) %>% 
 do(data.frame(., treat = sample(.$gender, 6, replace=TRUE)))
```

However, I am failing to introduce a `group_by` argument.

```
md %>% 
  bootstrap(10) %>% 
  group_by(party) %>% 
  do(data.frame(., treat = sample(.$gender, 6, replace=TRUE)))
```

Any idea ?

Also, `bootstrap` function is actually quite slow. Any idea why ? And any solution to make it faster ? Can we parallelise it somehow ?

```
library(reshape2)
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
md = melt(M)
```

Comment: Does `md %>% group_by(party) %>% bootstrap(10, by_group = TRUE) %>% do(data.frame(., treat = sample(.$gender, 6, replace=TRUE)))` work?

Comment: You wrote, *What I would like is to repeat this operation many times* But what is the expected output ?  What about using `replicate`?

Comment: @agstudy replicate is a possibility, I used it in the question mentioned. It just makes the codes cumbersome.

Comment: @Axeman no actually. It doesn't stratified properly. Any clue of parallelisation?

Comment: Parallelisation with `dplyr` can be done with the `multidplyr` package on github. But it's still kind of buggy, and it won't support `bootstrap`.

Comment: Thank you interesting. Hope it will be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution using `data.table` ( if you are looking for performance you should really give it a go)  package and `replicate`:

```
setDT(dx)
rbindlist(replicate(10,dx[,perm := sample(gender),party],simplify=FALSE))
```

I am not a user of `dplyr` neither a piper , but if your a "pipe-fanatic" you can transform the code above and pipe it:

```
PERM <- function(dx)
  dx[,perm := sample(gender),party]

REPLICATE <- function(dx,n)
  rbindlist(replicate(n,dx[,perm := sample(gender),party],simplify=FALSE))

dx %>%
  PERM() %>%
  REPLICATE(10)
```